Regexp to select everything except the specified string
I want to write a regexp that selects everything except the given sequence.

the sequence can be at the beginning of a word
the sequence can be in the middle

I was able to write something like this: ((?!patt).)+
It works almost well, but it matches everything except the first letter. Example https://regex101.com/r/WkAo7U/1
text: "pattern noster pattern" 
regexp: ((?!patt).)+ 
result: "attern noster attern"
wanted result: "ern noster ern"

A regex match is always a substring (no jumps). You cannot expect it to match pieces that are concatenated together without a program that does that. But as you tagged this with JavaScript, why not replace every occurrence of "patt" with the empty string?

You write that the result of our regex is "attern noster attern", but that is not true. It has two distinct matches: "attern noster " and "attern".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Simply split with your pattern.
